# How Can I implement this association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model

I want to implement a feature where user can "add new attributes" to his profile. Here he should be able to create the label for the detail and the actual details like:

```
Education : Degree
```

where Education is the label for the detail and Degree is the detail.

Apart from this, he should also have an option to decide whether this details should be made visible or hidden.

How can I implement this using a new model Profile with the association

`User has_one Profile`.

If I just had Label and Text for the new details, I could have tried hash, but since I would also have to get the details from the user on whether the user wants the detail to be made `hidden` or `visible`, I might require an extra field to store that value (true or false).So how can I implement that ?

I cannot create a `has_many Profile user_id:integer name:string content:string visible:boolean` since what I need is a has_one association.

I am really confused as to how I can get the whole thing implemented together.

Please suggest me how I can implement this and also how can I update the model each time a user creates a new detail without changing the `schema` of the db.

I am working on Rails 3.2.

Comment: "without changing the schema of the db", what schema do you have? You'll need a way to store the label and details for each attribute in the db.

Comment: @alfonso : I might need to serialize the key value pair and also the boolean. How could I do that ?

Comment: so you have only one field in the Profile table and you need to serialize all the attributes into that field? That's probably not a good choice. It might be better to have a ProfileAttributes table and model.

Comment: @alfonso  : I want to just have a single model Profile and uses serialize to CRUD the key value pair and boolean corresponding to each key-value pair. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a column named `attributes` of type text in your profile table

```
class AddAttributesToProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :profiles, :attributes, :text
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :profiles, :attributes
  end
end
```

Then you can use the serialize method in your model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base 
  serialize :attributes, Hash
end
```

This will allow you to write code like this:

```
profile.attributes = { :education => ["Chef degree", true], :hobby => ["Cook", false] }
profile.save
```

The Hash will be serialized in YAML format.

---

**Edit: CRUD operations**

To add or modify the education:

```
profile.attributes[:education] = ["Another title", true] # the boolean here represents the visibility
```

To query for all the visible attributes:

```
profile.attributes.each{|key, value| print "#{key.to_s.capitalize} : #{value.first}" if value.second}
```

To delete the education:

```
profile.attributes.delete :education
```

Comment: Thanks... But according to my requirement, my model name is Profile and it should have a key value pair and a boolean corresponding to it (visible/hidden). How could I CRUD the hash boolean pair especially Create a new attribute ie key,value and boolean

Comment: @MithunSasidharan I edited the answer to show the CRUD operations

Comment: You can use javascript to allow the user to add several attributes, or maybe use a grid-like control.

Comment: In a ge i want to display the already existing attributes and also have a button which on click will load a modal window and let me add new attribute and value. How could I save the new value once I submit it. Should I have multiple forms ? Please explain !!

Comment: It depends. One alternative is to have only one form and when the modal window is closed, update the content of the form with javascript. Then submit all the information with a save button below the form. You might want to open another question in SO to get more feedback.

Comment: Profile.new.detail = { :Education => ["Degree", true], :Linked In Profile => ["link", false] }
will not work since :Linked in Profile will break since it is not a single word

Comment: Use strings as the key then: `Profile.new.detail = { "Education" => ["Degree", true], "Linked In Profile" => ["link", false] }`

Comment: I am seriously stuck up with the form part of it in the view.. kindly help me with that !!

Comment: @MithunSasidharan try opening a new question detailing what you have so far, please

Answer (score 1):

I would create it through nested attributes.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fields
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :fields
end
```

then in view, i would put something like this

```
= form_for user do |f|
  = f.fields_for :profile do |p_form|
    = p_form.fields_for :fields do |f_form|
      = f_form :name
      = f_form :value
```

Comment: I want to just have a single model Profile and use serialize to CRUD the key value pair and boolean corresponding to each key-value pair. How can I do that ?